# How to find Jelly's share safe combination?

Tags: dishonored

It seems obvious that is has something to do with the bottles on the shelves behind the safe.  I don't know if it's due to my brightness configuration (perhaps too dark), but I wasn't able to see anything over there, or to find any item in the bottles...  So where is the combination ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code you're looking for is behind the bottles.
[image]

Answer (score 7):

The first key code combination in [LGS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looking_Glass_Studios) games, and since their demise companies who follow on in their spirit, is 451 or a variant thereof (e.g. 45100). This is a reference to Fahrenheit 451.

This means you can guess the combination quickly without even looking!

This tradition started in System Shock 1 and is followed by System Shock 2, Deus Ex, BioShock and now Dishonored :)

Comment: Oow, I had no idea about that !  Any idea about how that idea came to them ?  I couldn't find anything on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Have you look this video on Youtube?

Comment: Great, the video confirms that my brightness is way too low: I was unable to see a thing back there on the shelves.  Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Anto No problem but why you have removed the accepted answer ?

Comment: The other seemed more direct and clear than "look at this video" ;)

Answer (score -1):

Thats all wrong. The code is 528. Look at the note it says 3 months. Month of wind, month of seeds, and month of ice. Thats the order. In the book you will see different months all saying the month of whatever. And each month starting with wind is 5, seeds is 2, and ice is 8. Therefore the code is 528. I put it in myself and it opened.

Comment: You're thinking of a different safe.

Comment: Yeah, definitely.  Or perhaps it's different on other supports (console ?)

Comment: This is the combination for the safe in the final part of the game